# How to prove that $\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) - \frac{1}{x+1}$ is always positive and tends to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

What I get so far is the inequality:

$$1 + \frac{1}{x} > e^{\frac{1}{x+1}}$$

which if we expand:

$$1+\frac{1}{x} > 1+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2! (x+1)^2}+\cdots$$

and I cannot prove this inequality.

Someone give a hint please :)

Comment: What about proving that $\displaystyle \log\frac{x+1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1} > 0$ for all $x \in (0,1]$, and also that, if it is true for a certain $x = k$, it's also true for $x = k + 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
f(x)=\log\frac{1+x}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}
$$
defined for $x>0$ or $x<-1$. Let's look at $x>0$, for the moment. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0.
$$
Then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=
-\frac{1}{x(1+x)^2}
$$
So …

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

- $\log\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)=-\log(1-u)$ for $u=\frac1{x+1}$
- $\log(1+v)\leqslant v$ for every $v\gt-1$

Answer (score 0):

from the definition of $\ln,$ we have $$\ln\left(\frac{x+1}x\right)-\frac1{x+1} =\int_x^{x+1}\left(\frac 1t - \frac1{x+1}  \right)\, dt \ge 0 $$ the last inequality follows from the constraint $x > 0.$

we also have $$ \int_x^{x+1}\left(\frac 1t - \frac1{x+1}  \right)\, dt \le \frac1{x(x+1)} \to 0 \text{ as } x \to \infty.$$